# How to get the text value of a selected item from a DataList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datalist

How do I get the text value of the options in a DataList? 
I need to make use of the value of an `id`, But I also need the value of the selectedIndex, which is the name.

```
<input type="text" name="names[]" id="names" list="neym"/>
<datalist id="neym">
    <option value="example"></option>
    <option value="example2"></option>
    <option value="example3"></option>
</datalist>
```

How do I do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through them and use text() and val() as others have pointed out:

```
$('#neym option').each(function(index) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).text();

    // Do something with the id and name
    alert('Found ' + name + ' with id ' + id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering an input with a datalist data >>

to get **val()** try:

```
$("#inputid").val();
```

to get **text()** try:

```
$("#datalistid option[value='" + $('#inputid').val() + "']").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting selected index's text

```
$("#neym option:selected").text()
```

For getting selected index's value

```
$('#neym').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text inside the selected option

```
$( "#neym :selected" ).text();
```

Or to get it's value

```
$( "#neym :selected" ).val()
```

Comment: in what event should I put this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="option_box" list="my_options">
<datalist id="my_options">
</datalist>

document.getElementById('option_box').value;
```

The input element holds the value of the selected field in the datalist. This is a simple non jquery version of the answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer, however, you should expand it more. Please include an explanation of your code, and how it solves the asker's question/issue.

Comment: Add some description of exactly **what** and **why** you're doing it this way.