# Why getting the value of datalist is not working?

Tags: javascript

Ho can I alert the value of the selected option of my datalist, values are: 1,2 or 3.

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571158/how-to-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-item-from-a-datalist-using-jquery), it should work like it is.

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/gOMZarJ

HTML:

```
<div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
                <input value="1" type="range" max="3" min="1" step="1" list="performance_options">
                <datalist id="performance_options">
                    <option value="1">1080p</option>
                    <option value="2">1440p (2k)</option>
                    <option value="3">4K</option>
                </datalist>
                <output class="__range-output-square"></output>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
alert($('#performance_options').attr('value'));
```

alerts "undefined", expected 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Do you want to alert all options or just the selected one?

Comment: just selected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alert any option you should select it...

This will alert the first one:

```
alert($('#performance_options option').attr('value'));
```

And this will alert all of them:

```
$('#performance_options option').each(function(index, value) {
  alert(`option${index}: ${this.value}`);
});
```

---

Since you want to alert the one that the user select you should listen to the input change value and alert the same option text:

```
$('[type="range"]').on('change', function() {
  let val = this.value;
  alert($("#performance_options option[value=" + val + "]").prop("selected", true).text());
});
```

Comment: Don't need to alert all of them, just the one user selects. Preferable the last one he chooses.

Comment: I've tried this, and this alerts every option, only need to alert selected one, and on load set option 1 as the default. ty. Because, I need the selected value to send it to backend, just one value.